# How to automate date sting with glue

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, r-glue

I'm trying to automate DateTime to always generate a report on t+1

so I did

the date format in the df is like this 2021-12-21 23:59:52
2021-12-21 21:37:50
2021-12-21 19:41:18
2021-12-21 19:21:36
2021-12-21 19:15:41
2021-12-21 19:15:36

```
yesterday<- Sys.Date()-1 #this will always do yesterday date
```

so whenever you see {yesterday}

I want to filter the DateTime

so I did

```
df%>%
    filter(Status == "SUCCESSFUL" & glue:glue(Date >= "{yesterday} 19:15:36" & Date<= 
        "{yesterday} 23:59:59"))
```

but I'm getting this error below

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `&...`.
x All unnamed arguments must be length 1
```

I know the problem is the glue::glue
can someone help me rearrange my code pls

Comment: Maybe use `dplyr::between(Date, lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(yesterday, "19:15:36")), lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(yesterday, "23:59:59")))` as a condition. You may want to ensure that time zones of `df$Date` and `ymd_hms(...)` are as expected before comparing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come across a solution for the question

I realize that I needed to glue both before >= and <= to the time which goes like this

```
df%>%
filter(Status == "SUCCESSFUL" &
DateTime >= glue("{yesterday} 00:00:00") &
DateTime<= glue("{yesterday} 23:59:59"))
```

Thanks